# HapiJS encoding problems using views

Tags: html, node.js, template-engine, hapi.js

When using views to render content using special characters, I experience this:

```
reply.view('index.jade', {name : 'Pagès'}); //outputs "PagÃ¨s"
```

Template is just :

```
p #{name}
```

But, if i just send the plain text, it works ok:

```
reply('<p>Pagès</p>');  //outputs "Pagès"
```

I tried with Jade and EJS, and both render it wrong, so I think problem is related to Hapi.

Following code (via command line) discards Jade issues:

```
var jade = require('jade');
var fn = jade.compile('p #{name}');
var html = fn({name : 'Pagès'});
console.log(html);   // output ok -> <p>Pagès</p>
```

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `!{name}`?

Comment: I have tried, and no luck :( Thx for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your browser is interpreting the web page as [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

By default, Hapi encodes its response with the utf-8 charset. This is what you want. You can double-check that this is the case by looking at the HTTP response in the network tools. But it's unlikely this would be the issue.

The likely culprit is a lack of clarification on the encoding within your HTML page. Try adding the following code in the `<head>` element of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

This specifies the character encoding for the document, and should iron out any character encoding issues during the render.